# Lambda expression in list of object

Tags: c#, lambda

I have one list as below. I need to write the lambda expression to show the response which have maximum score. Can anyone please help?

```
list [0] - response : "Hi"
           ScoreData : {{"score" : "99"}}
     [1] - response : "Hello"
           ScoreData: {{"score" : "100"}}
     [2] - response : "how are you"
           ScoreData: {{"score" : "101"}}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the list? Is it a `List<T>` or `Dictionary<T1,T2>`? And what is the type of data it holds?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the type definition for the response items in your list. Other than that, you will need to sort your list using LINQ's OrderBy and then pick the first entry like this:

`var highestScore = list.OrderByDescending(x => /* get score */).First();`

Comment: @michivo or do something `O(n)` rather than `O(n log n)`.

Comment: List<T> but ScoreData is object type. So firstly I am doing JObject.Parse(list.ScoreData.ToString()) and then according to key getting score value. But I want to do in lambda expression only because there would be many records like this.